# Change Image on Active <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 2-tab content slider for the mobile section of my site. The user clicks on the linked image within the `<li>` element and the corresponding content loads. I would like the image to change color when in an "active" state, so pretty much a new image to be loaded when the user clicks it.

This is only for mobile sites so please bear that in mind when offering solutions. Thanks All!!

```
<div id="tabs" class='tabs no-screen no-ie'>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab-1"><img src="img/mobile/bingo.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Super Free Bingo" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab-2"><img src="img/mobile/slots.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Super Free Logo" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
  <div id='tab-1' class="tab-box">
    <?php include 'includes/sfb.php'; ?>
  </div>
  <div id='tab-2' class="tab-box">
    <?php include 'includes/sfsg.php'; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably do those images with css as a background for li and have different backgrounds for li and li:active. You can not simply change color of an image unless you use some graphics manipulating library.

Comment: hover has issues on mobile though right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood that correctly, when the user clicks the image, the image changes. Seeing as you only have two images, we can do the following:

Add a unique id to your target images.

```
<img src="img/mobile/bingo.png" id="image-1">
<img src="img/mobile/slots.png" id="image-2">
```

Add a JavaScript OnClick event for each image that will also reset the other image.

```
$('#image-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/mobile/newImage1.png');
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#image-2').attr('src', 'img/mobile/slots.png');
    $('#image-2').parent().parent().css('background-color', 'orange');
});

$('#image-2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/mobile/newImage2.png');
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#image-1').attr('src', 'img/mobile/bingo.png');
    $('#image-1').parent().parent().css('background-color', 'orange');
});
```

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines, but how to revert it back to original image when other image is clicked?

Comment: You could do that in the click function as well. `$(otherImage).attr('src', 'img/oldImage.png')`

Comment: Any chance of a complete script, JS scares me

Comment: Bit of confusion I think, you can check out the url on a mobile for reference (http://www.littlestarmedia.com/alpha/#what-page)

Hang on, ignore this for the moment

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me if you're referring to the "2" and "cherry" tabs. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you have site up on mobile?

Comment: Yup. And clicking the tabs is changing the image.

Comment: Ok, So I have an orange and black version of each image.

I basically need it to switch from Orange on White Background to Black on Orange background, make sense?

Comment: Oh you shoulda mentioned background-color too. I added some code that changes the background colors as well. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No problem. Site looks great by the way!

Comment: Thanks! my first duty at new position :)

Answer (score 1):

Check This Demo for reference

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3VCf/)

```
$(".a").click(function(){
$(".a").each(function(index){
   $("#id"+(index+1)+" a img").attr('src',a[index]); 
});
var x=$(this).attr('id');
var y=x.split('id')[1];
$("#id"+(y)+" a img").attr('src',b[y-1]); 
});
```